# How to insert a variable into a file path?

Tags: python, string

I have the following code:

```
import os

current_user = os.getlogin()

target_path = r"C:\Users\{I want the current user variable inserted here}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

but it just prints out as

```
"C:\Users\current_user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals), not a raw string:

```py
import os

current_user = os.getlogin()

target_path = rf"C:\Users\{current_user}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

We use `rf` rather than `f` here, as we need to prevent `\U` from being interpreted as a Unicode escape sequence, as [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11082165/brian) points out.

Comment: The `\U` in that f-string will cause a syntax error unless the ``\`` is escaped or a raw string is used. A raw f-string `rf"..."` is likely the best choice

Comment: Edited, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you want

```
target_path = rf"C:\Users\{current_user}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

but even better is

```
target_path = os.environ["APPDATA"]+"\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup"
```

Comment: "Even better" would use `pathlib`, IMO